# É possível identificar o banco de dados de origem de uma stored procedure em SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Tenho uma stored-procedure em SQL 'spr_insere_carga_pedido' onde ao executar o comando sp_helptext em um determinado  banco ela não  foi  identificada; existiria alguma maneira de identificar o banco de dados onde essa stored procedure foi criada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível.

Basicamente todos os objetos do banco estão em tabelas como `sys.tables`, `sys.procedures` e `sys.objects`, bastaria fazer um select nelas, mas essas tabelas existem em cada database, então precisaria executar o select em todos os databases individualmente.

Para resolver isso, existe uma procedure que faz um `foreach` em todos os databases, que é a `sp_MSforeachdb`.

Daí fica simples, basta fazer um select na tabela `sysobjects` buscando pelo nome da procedure, filtrando pelo campo `xtype='P'`, que é "procedure" (a sysobjects tem todos os objetos do banco, como tables e functions) e no select adicionar o `db_name()` para listar o nome do banco.

Fica assim:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'select db_name(), * From ?..sysobjects where xtype = ''P'' And name = ''spr_insere_carga_pedido'''
```

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu mesmo!